# Vibration on touch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-vibration

I have some buttons and need my phone vibrate on touch this buttons.

How I can do this?

Code of button for example

```
Button sushi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.sushiButton);
sushi.Click += delegate {
            var intent24 = new Intent (this, typeof(SushiActivity));
            StartActivity (intent24);

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

to vibrate, do this (assuming you are calling from within an Activity):

```
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
vib.Vibrate(50);
```

You will also need to enable this permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```